# Error 404 on uploading blob to production server on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, file-upload, blobstore

I'm building a system where the users will upload articles to my app and I need to store them. I've read the tutorial about blobhandlers on Google's documentation and it worked, but only local.
When I test the app on development server, everything is fine, but on production server, I get Error 404 and the following logs:

```
2014-02-17 08:59:28.490 /http://ciro-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6ah2vpKNsIDSzlpYPqAgnQ_zznnUwDweG571CgMMnGlluXc1GJS0i42UYYOKVZNQMBhzyY3grQFeCgD4hf4usx_YeMwy4n_93qM-QFegsMIFHDkNovRcJ9Rnl9li91bo4bdClfV/ALBNUaYAAAAAUwJCQ_kw2ANG1Tnvs9OIU6cAyOUDscqL/ 404 19ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36 module=default version=1
186.226.15.242 - - [17/Feb/2014:08:59:28 -0800] "POST /http://ciro-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6ah2vpKNsIDSzlpYPqAgnQ_zznnUwDweG571CgMMnGlluXc1GJS0i42UYYOKVZNQMBhzyY3grQFeCgD4hf4usx_YeMwy4n_93qM-QFegsMIFHDkNovRcJ9Rnl9li91bo4bdClfV/ALBNUaYAAAAAUwJCQ_kw2ANG1Tnvs9OIU6cAyOUDscqL/ HTTP/1.1" 404 188 "http://ciro-app-id.appspot.com/enviar" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36" "ciro-app-id.appspot.com" ms=20 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000021 app_engine_release=1.9.0 instance=00c61b117c6c9b0c25f5b86e2eadac83e2908691
```

Here is my code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1-lpPH97tV2dzN6aURYVENCMzQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my app: ciro-app-id.appspot.com

**Try it yourself**

Login credentials:

Email: ciromoraismedeiros@gmail.com

Password: 123

Access ciro-app-id.appspot.com/enviar fill the form and submit it.
Obs.: I'm Brazillian, so everything is in portuguese language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the leading "/" in your request log? In /templates/enviar_artigo.html, change

```
<form action='/{{upload_url}}' ...>
```

to

```
<form action='{{upload_url}}' ...>
```